# CSS for shrinking image from left in smaller devices

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

In a responsive site, when an image shrinks widht-wise to fit in a smaller device it does so by keeping the left side fixed while the right side is being cut off. Is there a sytle to do the inverse? Fix the right while cutting the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use background instead of image and set `background-position: right`

Here is a short demo

```css
div {
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/400/200');
}

#left {
  background-position: left; /* this is the default value */
}

#right {
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
background-position: right;
OR
download a smaller version of the picture from Unsplash